# JHipster support websockets in microservice architecture

Tags: websocket, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I tried to implement websockets in one of the microservices in my project. However, I found out the Zuul proxy doesn't support websockets by default and jhipster developers is recommending adding websockets to gateway project as in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7335 . Are there any better solution for this problem using a different proxy that will allow adding websockets to microservice?

Comment: Traefik supports websockets https://www.jhipster.tech/traefik/

Comment: One way to do it is to separate the frontend from the gateway and serve it through nginx (see https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/) then you can use nginx features to proxy websocket requests.